# E2250 There is no overloaded version of 'StrPas' that can be called with these arguments

Tags: delphi

My code :

```
function ThisModuleName: Char; //bulo String
var
  p: array [0..512] of char;
  fileNamePart: pchar;
begin
  GetModuleFileName(HInstance, @p[0], 512);
  GetFullPathName(@p[0], 512, @p[0], fileNamePart);
  result := StrPas(WideString(@p[0])); //stalo WideString
end;
```

In Delphi 7 compiles.
In Delphi 10.2 it gives an error:

```
[dcc32 Error] verinfo.pas(98): E2250 There is no overloaded version of 'StrPas' that can be called with these arguments
```

Comment: Did you cast a Char pointer to a WideString in Delphi 7? And that worked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code is wrong on all Delphi versions. I doubt it compiles anywhere. I'm guessing that the code you presented is not the Delphi 7 code, but rather the code after you've hacked at it for a while.

The return type should be `string` and not `char`. Furthermore, the cast to `WideString` is bogus. Finally, a zero-based array of characters can be treated as `PChar`.

Your function should be translated like so:

```
function ThisModuleName: string;
var
  p: array [0..511] of Char;
  fileNamePart: PChar;
begin
  GetModuleFileName(HInstance, p, Length(p));
  GetFullPathName(p, Length(p), p, fileNamePart);
  Result := p;
end;
```

Having said all of that, while this is a faithful translation of the code in the question, it does not return a module name. I really don't know what your code is trying to do, but the call to `GetFullPathName` appears to be wrong in your code.

My guess is that you are trying to convert potential short 8.3 file names to long names. I believe that you need an extra buffer to make that work. Here's what that code looks like, with some error checking added:

```
function ThisModuleName: string;
var
  ModuleFileName, Buffer: array [0..511] of Char;
  FilePart: PChar;
begin
  Win32Check(GetModuleFileName(HInstance, ModuleFileName, Length(ModuleFileName))<>0);
  Win32Check(GetFullPathName(ModuleFileName, Length(Buffer), Buffer, FilePart)<>0);
  Result := Buffer;
end;
```

Instead of asking a question for every problem you encounter in your porting project it might pay dividends to learn a bit more about Unicode Delphi.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of calling the API directly, you can call [System.SysUtils.GetModuleName](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.SysUtils.GetModuleName), which simply returns a string.

It wraps GetModuleFilename, and by doing so it also shows how to call that function. I hope I'm allowed to quote a couple of lines from the unit mentioned above. It also uses the MAX_PATH constant, which contains the maximum length of a path.

Note that GetModuleFilename already returns a fully qualified path, so calling GetFullPathName afterwards is redundant.

```
function GetModuleName(Module: HMODULE): string;
var
  ModName: array[0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
begin
  SetString(Result, ModName, GetModuleFileName(Module, ModName, Length(ModName)));
end;
```

This is mainly useful if you want the path of a dll, if you're interested in the main executable, you can simply use `Application.ExeName`.

Comment: This doesn't do the same as the code in the question. I admit that the code in the question makes a quite bizarre call to `GetFullPathName`. One has to wonder what the asker is actually trying to do.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The result is actually the same since [GetModuleFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/windows/desktop/ms683197(v=vs.85).aspx) already returns a fully qualified filename, so [GetFullPathName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364963(v=vs.85).aspx) is redundant.

Comment: `MAX_PATH` is 260, both in the [API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#maxpath) and the RTL (windows.pas).

Comment: Depressing to see `array[0..MAX_PATH] of Char`, an array of length `MAX_PATH+1`. Emba are so disappointing.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yup it is. That's VCL quality for you. :p

Comment: Technically it doesn't matter what size buffer you pass to GetModuleFileName as long as you specify its length correctly. But of course it's not semantically good practice to use MAX_PATH if your buffer's length is different.

Comment: Note that [sysutils.GetModuleName](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.SysUtils.GetModuleName) may not return a fully qualified name since [sysutils.GetModuleFileName](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.GetModuleFileName) may not return a fully qualified name, stated as warnings in the docs.